# Looking for suggestions on whether I should tear up this lawn or try to condition it

Tags: lawn, grass, fertilizer

I have a front lawn that needs some major help.  Trying to determine if I need to tear it up or try to condition it.

I have a skunk that is digging small holes, but when I dig for grubs I don't find anything.

Any thoughts on what to do?  I am in lower Michigan, so the lawn has still not fully come back yet.[image]

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, that looks better than my Wisconsin front lawn, which I've partially given up on and will convert to a garden. I'd condition your lawn - far fewer weeds than mine, for one thing. Aeration and top-dressing with compost should work wonders. Keep it well-watered, too, especially if we head into drought again (1 inch a week from 1 watering a week). I'd avoid any herbicides this year, unless you have crabgrass (and then not even that if you're reseeding).